# Cached fragment never expires

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application for managing public events. Within the a view I am trying to cache a fragment which expires every 8 hours. The fragment caches successfully but never expires. Looking at the site today the fragment is showing events from the 23rd June, which is the last time I manually flushed the fragment cache.

I'm currently using the following snippet which renders a list of event titles and dates:

```
- cache('sidebar-cache', :expires_in => 8.hour) do
    = render "shared/sidebar_festivals"
```

I have also tried the following (24 hours instead of 8) with the same issue:

```
- cache "sidebar_cache", expires: 1.day.from_now(Time.now.beginning_of_day)
    = render "shared/sidebar_festivals"
```

I have caching enabled in the `production.rb` config file:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

Is there something else I need to enable or do for fragment caching to expire?

I'm using Rails 4.2.1

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was having is related to timezones. The time zone on the server was set to Eastern Standard Time whereas the server was actually located in London. The rails app was using UTC. The mismatch was enough to cause this issue.

To set the time on a Ubuntu server, as I'm using here, run this command as root and follow the prompts

```
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```